# Automatically update columns values after 6 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a new table in MySQL, I want to make changes in ( column1 and column2 ) columns values automatically in sql.

I tried this code, but their is no changes in table after 6 days.

```
CREATE EVENT weekly
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 6 days
    STARTS DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL (6 DAYS(NOW())+1) DAY
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
UPDATE INTO `MyTable` (`value1`, `value2`) 
SELECT `column1` , `column2`)
WHERE `column1` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6*24 HOUR;
```

Comment: Have you checked for error in the logs?

Comment: 1) Your schedule needs to be daily.  2) the UPDATE statement syntax is not right

Comment: @JayBlanlchard yes

Comment: @PeterHe can you write the solution please ?

Comment: is the ) after column2 a typo here?

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE statement is not correct. It should be like below -

```
UPDATE `MyTable`
SET `column1` = ???
   ,`column2` = ???
WHERE `column1` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6*24 HOUR;
```

Replace `???` with the the value you want to update in col1 and col2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to update the value for column1 and 2. But the event should look like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS daily_update
ON SCHEDULE 
   EVERY 1 DAY STARTS DATE(NOW())
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
COMMENT 'Update myTable after 6 days'
DO 
BEGIN
  UPDATE MyTable
  SET column1='value1',
      column2='value2'
  WHERE column1>= (NOW() - INTERVAL 6*24 HOUR);
END
//
```